# Are these examples correct or the tutorial has an error?

Tags: haskell, liquid-haskell

I am reading [this tutorial](https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-tutorial/02-logic.html) and I am not sure that I understand correctly the text (or that it is correct at whole). There is an example:

> The following predicates are valid because they encode modus ponens:
>   if you know that a implies b and you know that a is true, then it must
>   be the case that b is also true:

```
{-@ ex6 :: Bool -> Bool -> TRUE @-}
ex6 a b = (a && (a ==> b)) ==> b

{-@ ex7 :: Bool -> Bool -> TRUE @-}
ex7 a b = a ==> (a ==> b) ==> b
```

and ex6 is fine, but ex7 is not, it fails for `a = false` and `b = false`. And LH repot it as:

```
Error: Liquid Type Mismatch

 88 | ex7 a b = a ==> (a ==> b) ==> b
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   Inferred type
     VV : {v : GHC.Types.Bool | v <=> ((a => (a => b)) => b)}

   not a subtype of Required type
     VV : {VV : GHC.Types.Bool | VV}

   In Context
     a : GHC.Types.Bool

     b : GHC.Types.Bool
```

Also I don't understand their definition of the implication: "You should read p ==> q as if p is true then q must also be true". It does not sound correctly, because it asserts only one case: `T -> T = T`. What do I miss here? May be tutorial has error in "ex7"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect in the example, they have made `(==>)` right associative, while in your tests you left it at the default, which is left associative. Compare:

```
> infixl 9 ==>; False ==> x = True; True ==> x = x
> False ==> (False ==> False) ==> False
False
> infixr 9 ==>; False ==> x = True; True ==> x = x
> False ==> (False ==> False) ==> False
True
```

The [Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-820004.4.2) has further details.